# fork/join, synchronization necessary on input array?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, fork-join, java-memory-model

I have a large array of objects and want to collect all objects with certain field value and because it is such a large array, i plan on using fork/join in java.

the large array is forked not by creating a new sub lists but by passing in original list but with start/end range. compute finds all objects that meets certain predicate and add them to a passed in ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
After join of all subtasks, write ConcurrentLinkedQueue to a storage.

Does the input large list have to be synchronized list? I believe not because of thread-start happens-before rule, i think its state at the start of fork/join execution would be visible to any tasks/threads. But i wanted to confirm my understanding is correct.

Comment: If the list is static, then you are correct. The preferred way is for each thread to work on a section of the list. However, since you don't say what kind of list you're using (is it modifiable?) then we need more info.

Comment: yes the list does not change once forkjoin is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *happens-before* edges associated with various fork-join actions, so you can usually piggyback off of those without needing additional synchronization.  However, you might find that the following (which uses FJ under the hood) gives you the answer you want with much less work:

```
Element[] matching = 
    Stream.of(largeArray)
          .parallel()
          .filter(e -> e.theField.equals(theTargetValue))
          .toArray();
```

Comment: thanks Brian, I read your Java Concurrency in Practice and i am a fan. would love to see a new edition with this kind of recommendation!

Comment: @user21479 Me too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is thread-safe for the reason you stated.